# pandas Calculating ratio as values in pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, crosstab

I have a Df which looks like this:

```
    tests  Machine  results
    111    A        OK
    111    A        OK
    111    A        OK
    111    A        NOK
    111    B        OK
    222    A        OK
    333    A        OK
    333    B        OK
    444    A        OK
    222    A        NOK
    222    A        OK
    111    B        OK
```

I want to have a matrix/pivot table where rows should be tests and columns should be machines and values should be ratio/percentage of tests that are OK to the overall count of tests for each machine.

results should be:

```
   OK/total cnt  A     B
   111           75%   100%   #test 111 passed 3 out of 4 tests in machine A and all tests in B
   222           50%   0%     #test 222 passed 1 out of 2 tests in machine A and 0 tests prfrmd in B
   333           100%  100%   #test 333 passed all tests in A and B machines
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get column for rows that are equal to `OK`, then run a [crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) to get your average

```
df = df.assign(passed=df.results.eq("OK"))

(
    pd.crosstab(df.tests, df.Machine, df.passed, aggfunc="mean")
    .rename_axis(columns=None, index="OK/total cnt")
    .mul(100, fill_value=0)
)

                  A           B
OK/total cnt        
  111           75.000000   100.0
  222           66.666667   0.0
  333          100.000000   100.0
  444          100.000000   0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Create new column by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with compare for `OK` by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html), then pivoting by default `mean` method in [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html), multiple by `100` and last if necessary convert index to `column`:

```
df = (df.assign(res = df['results'].eq('OK'))
        .pivot_table(index='tests',
                     columns='Machine', 
                     values='res', 
                     fill_value=0)
        .mul(100)
        .rename_axis(index='OK/total cnt', columns=None)
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   OK/total cnt           A    B
0           111   75.000000  100
1           222   66.666667    0
2           333  100.000000  100
3           444  100.000000    0
```